# How does polygonal effect affect the effect of angular synchronization in car engines' timing train drive?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

Is a regular roller train drive used in most car engine's timing chain drive? If so, wouldn't the polygonal effect affect the accuracy of strict angular synchronization between the camshafts and the crankshaft?

Comment: what is a "roller train"? do you mean roller *chain*?

Comment: If it is a significant effect, why do you think the engineers who designed the cams would have ignored it? You can just change the shape of the cam to compensate for it.

Comment: The polygons effect is negligible as the number of rollers are greater than 16 rolls.

Answer (score 1):

One checks if the crank and cams are in time after fitting a new chain by completing two full revolutions of the cranshaft, they should, and normally do if all is correct, come back to the correct positions.